# KoaJS blocking main thread

Tags: ecmascript-6, koa

I have the following koa server

```
const koa = require('koa');
const router = require('koa-router')();

// Intialize the base application
const app = koa();

// Define the logger function
app.use(function *(next) {
    console.log('Start processing');

    // before (Downstream)
    var timestampBefore = new Date().getTime();

    yield next;

    // After (Upstream)
    var timestampAfter = new Date().getTime();
    var difference = timestampAfter - timestampBefore;

    console.log("Processing took " + difference + "ms");
});

// Intialize router
app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods());

router.get('/users', function *() {
    yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(this.body = ['User 1', 'User 2']), 3000);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Listening'));
```

I'm hitting the `/users` endpoint from two clients at the same time. I would expect it not to block the main thread and process both requests at the same time. Instead what I can see in the console is

```
Server Listening
Start processing
Processing took 3007ms
Start processing
Processing took 3005ms
```

Instead of

```
Server Listening
Start processing
Start processing
Processing took 3007ms
Processing took 3005ms
```

Comment: this is still happening. any insight found?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code on my machine and had similar logging, however I changed it a bit as shown:

```
router.get('/users', function *() {
    if (this.query.fast === '1'){
      this.body = ['User 3', 'User 4']
    }
    else{
      yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(this.body = ['User 1', 'User 2']), 5000);
      });
    }

});
```

Then I do a `GET` to `http://localhost:3000/users` which wait's in setTimeout, then I immediately do a `GET` to `http://localhost:3000/users?fast=1` and it returns a result immediately.  Just to show that there is no blocking.

```
$node server.js
Server Listening
Start processing
Start processing
Processing took 6ms
Processing took 5005ms
```

Not really sure why the log makes it seem like the thread is blocked, maybe some buffering, but I think it's just misleading.

Comment: Actually you could leave the code as is and just add a query string. You will have the same result. I think that Koa might check if the same request comes from the same IP then it just block it until the previous one has finished.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a query string to the end of the url makes it work as expected. This makes me think that Koa might block the requests to the same entity if it's coming from he same IP address.

That's just a speculation, though.